# Setting DefaultDataPath and DefaultLogPath on Deploy in VS2010 Database Project

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, database-project

To be true the following query is not originally mine, but I am facing the exact issue in my work. And thus copying the problem statement as it is. I am not able to find any solution. I would really appreciate any suggestions or highlights of the following Problem Set:

> I do not have any hardcoding in Schema Objects\Database Level
>   Objects\Storage\Files - both in database and log files.
>
> The deployment script that gets generated when I click "deploy" from
>   db project has hardcoding in :SETVAR with database and log file path
>   assigned to $(DefaultDataPath) and $(DefaultLogPath) - see below:
>   :setvar DefaultDataPath "C:\DB\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10_50.MITCHELL\MSSQL\DATA\" :setvar DefaultLogPath
>   "C:\DB\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MITCHELL\MSSQL\DATA\".
>
> I want the deployment script to accept input for data and log path. 
>   But based on script that is being currently generated, I'll have to
>   manually comment the above 2 lines and modifiy the CREATE DATABASE
>   statement as shown below every single time to replace any reference to
>   "DefaultDataPath" and "DefaultLogPath" with "InputDefaultDataPath" and
>   "InputDefaultLogPath" CREATE DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
>       ON 
>       PRIMARY(NAME = [TEST_DB], FILENAME = '$(InputDefaultDataPath)$(DatabaseName).mdf', >SIZE = 3072 KB,
>   FILEGROWTH = 1024 KB)
>       LOG ON (NAME = [TEST_DB_log], FILENAME = >'$(InputDefaultLogPath)$(DatabaseName)_log.ldf', SIZE = 1024 KB,
>   MAXSIZE = 2097152 MB, FILEGROWTH = 10 %) COLLATE
>   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
>
> ```
>  Question 1: How do I prevent db project from scripting the below two lines and also
> ```
>
> prevent it from subsituting these variables in
>   CREATE DATABASE statement? :setvar DefaultDataPath "C:\DB\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MITCHELL\MSSQL\DATA\" :setvar DefaultLogPath
>   "C:\DB\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MITCHELL\MSSQL\DATA\".
>
> Question 2: How do I make db project to automaticaly script deployment
>   script in such a way that it accepts user input for DefaultDataPath
>   and DefaultLogPath without me manually changing it to include
>   $(InputDefaultDataPath) and  $(InputDefaultLogPath) variable?

Answer (score 3):

In visual studio 2010, there is a project setting called 'CommentOutSetVarDeclarations'. If you check this option, the two default SETVAR lines you mention will be commented out.

This enables you to supply values for $(DefaultDataPath) and $(DefaultLogPath) from the command line when running the deployment script from SQLCMD.

Comment: In VS2012 I had to add this to the publish profile xml <CommentOutSetVarDeclarations>True</CommentOutSetVarDeclarations>